# How to reinstall Linux Mint on an existing LVM (on LUKS) volume?

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, luks

I have done a standard Linux Mint install with encryption and LVM enabled. Then I have shrunk that LVM and created a separate /home using this [guide](https://www.dwarmstrong.org/rearrange-lvm-after-mint-install/) such that I could easily reinstall Linux later without having to touch my /home.

Now I want to keep the LUKS and LVM and just reinstall Mint into that LVM, wiping my root directory but keeping /home.

What I've tried:

- Run the Mint live CD again
- Unlock my encrypted root and home partitions in nemo
- Install the new system to the unlocked (encrypted) root partition and mounting all the other partitions/volumes to where they've been before

But after I restart the system, it won't boot and give back the error: "Volume group 'vgmint' not found"

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!

[Apparently the Ubuntu / Linux Mint installer is currently buggy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1904270), but there is an easy workaround.

- For 20.04-based Mint / Ubuntu installs see the [initial post of the before linked website](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1904270)
- For 22.04-based see [post #12 of said website](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1904270/comments/12) (the author made a mistake in his guide though: instead of `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX sdX_crypt` use `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX sdX_crypt`. Using sudo will return something like "sudo not found".

Comment: Whenever you are dropped into initramfs prompt, you are typically already root, so `sudo` is not necessary. Because of this, there is little reason to include `sudo` in initramfs at all.